# Use ARM functions from PowerShell

Tags: json, azure, devops, azure-rm-template

### TL;DR

The following line works fine as part of an ARM script ran in an Azure DevOps `ARM Template Deployment` task but, when ran from PowerShell, it fails to pull the subscription and the resource group.

```
"serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription(), '/resourcegroups/', resourceGroup(), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
```

how can I set the subscription and resource group variables so the ARM functions can pull the values?

P.S. It's ok If I have to first get them and then set them manually for the script to consume, as long as I can use the same script for DevOps and PowerShell.

---

Here's the resources section of the template which, again, when deployed from a pipeline it pulls the subscription and the resource group from whatever is set in the task parameters.

```
"resources": [
{
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "name": "[parameters('name')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {},
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('name')]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "metadata": [
        {
          "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
          "value": "[parameters('currentStack')]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription(), '/resourcegroups/', resourceGroup(), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
    "clientAffinityEnabled": true
  }
},
{
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "kind": "",
  "tags": {},
  "dependsOn": [],
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
  },
  "sku": {
    "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
    "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
  }
}
]
```

Comment: Could you please share the Powershell command that you use to deploy your ARM template ?

Comment: Your answer was the solution, adding the `.subscriptionId` and `.name` got it running from powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscription()` and `resourceGroup()` do return **objects** based on your context. You should consider querying attributes instead like : `subscription().subscriptionId` and `resourceGroup().name` considering how you are constructing your ID. I am not sure why it works in your ARM template though.

As a side comment, you could make use of the `resourceId([subscriptionId], [resourceGroupName], resourceType, resourceName1, [resourceName2], ...)` function as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid), under the hood it performs the same as you did (concat).

Comment: I tested it from PS and it worked, later today I'll rerun the pipeline to ensure that it continues to work from the pipeline, if so I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!